# How to raise an event in VB.NET when a row is added to an SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Not sure this is possible. Currently, to detect that a row has been added to a table in SQL Server, I use a timer to query the table. Is there a way SQL Server (presumably via the ADO.NET `SqlConnection` object) can raise an event in Visual Basic when a row is added, so I don't need to keep polling/querying the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, you can  use [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043.aspx) and [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The the setup is a bit complicated.  In short you use [SqlDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
The dependency first has to be created

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(CS)
```

And then  it can be used

```
Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand(SQLQuery, cn)
cmd.CommandText = "select field from dbo.MyTable"

sqlD = New SqlDependency(Cmd) 

cn.Open()
Dim tbl As New DataTable
tbl.Load(Cmd.ExecuteReader)

AddHandler sqlD.OnChange, AddressOf TableChanged
```

The dependency should not be used by lot of clients and there are strict rules ([Creating a Query for Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx)) how the query should be written.

Comment: That looks like what I'm after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a trigger to your table that calls your application whenever an updated happens. But I guess polling would be cleaner than calling your app from the database. Just keep the request small and if there's a change load the full data you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to the table and from there [call a webservice](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428200/How-to-invoke-a-Web-Service-from-a-Stored-Procedur). If there a lot of data being added, I would suggest keeping to your current method and call the database periodicaly.

You could always add a "item not process" table. Add an item in this table when something is being inserted and just query this table (which will be smaller).

There's also tutorial on [how to call .net dll from SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server-2005) but I don't know enought to suggest it.